# Barcode Boarding Pass Scanner

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

is there any way to scan barcode boarding passes  (BCBP) on Android which are not mobile boarding passes?

For example this Ryanair printed boarding pass:
http://www.lanzaroteinformation.com/files/Ryanair_Boarding_Pass_2.png

I was unable to successfully scan this barcode using Zxing library in my Android app. This type of code is PDF 417 if I'm correct and Zxing library supports it.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify it clearly. Yes it is programming related question. I was trying to get it implemented on Android but without luck. 
Using Zxing library it was hard to decode such barcodes.
Updated the question.